# Syntax error in store procedure mysql

Tags: mariadb, stored-procedures

```
BEGIN

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tblEmployeeAttendance;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tblEmployeeAttendance AS
SELECT emp.emp_id,emp.emp_name,x.attendance_date,
CASE
  WHEN x.CheckIN ='0' and x.Checkout = '1' THEN '1'
  WHEN x.CheckIN ='0' and x.Checkout is null then '2'
  WHEN x.CheckIN is null and x.Checkout = '1' then '3'
  ELSE '0'
END AS Status
FROM tbl_employee emp INNER JOIN
(
SELECT emp.emp_id,emp.emp_name,att.attendance_date,
   max(case when att.inorout ='0' then att.inorout end) as 'CheckIN',
  max(case when att.inorout ='1' then att.inorout end) as 'Checkout'
FROM tbl_employee emp
LEFT JOIN employee_attendance att
ON emp.emp_id = att.emp_code
WHERE att.attendance_date >= DATE_FORMAT(search_startdate, '%Y-%m-%d')
AND  att.attendance_date <= DATE_FORMAT(search_enddate, '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY emp.emp_id,att.attendance_date
) x  ON emp.emp_id = x.emp_id
GROUP BY x.emp_id,x.attendance_date;


SET @@group_concat_max_len = 75000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(CASE WHEN calemp.calendarDate = ''',
      date_format(calendarDate, '%Y-%m-%d'),
      ''' THEN coalesce(att.Status, 0) END) AS `',
      date_format(calendarDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM yearly_date_calendar
where calendarDate >= DATE_FORMAT(search_startdate, '%Y-%m-%d')
  and calendarDate <= DATE_FORMAT(search_enddate, '%Y-%m-%d');


PREPARE statement FROM @query;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
DROP TABLE tblEmployeeAttendance;
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 1024;
END
```

I am getting this error:

> MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Comment: You are building a string named sql, and preparing a string named query. Is that intentional? It's difficult to look for errors without the ability to test. If possible create a dbfiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk) or similar with all necessary tables, or add the tables in your query.

Comment: Add full code - from `CREATE PROCEDURE` till final `END;`. Specify WHEN this error occures - when you create procedure or when you execute it? Solve the problem of inconsistency in variable names and show the final query text which you try to prepare. And specify your server version.

Comment: What is the value of `@query`?  Where are the `DELIMITER` statements?